# First and Last visible items in a div with overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all i know there are similar threads but most of them use li items and i'm geeting too confused to use that code for my benefit.

Here it is... I have an element with overflow and some max-height for it. Inside i have another div elements and an anchor with my data in each one.
I want to be able to tell if the parent has overflown and if it is, do something.
Depending the cases i want last/first div in the overflown that is **visible** to do something.

What's better than an example... so here is my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyupm/3/)

And the basic logic in Jquery i want to implement in comments:

```
var container = $('#content_wrapper');
var items = container.children('.box_wrap');

//If div is overflown then do:
/items.each(function() {
    //If scroll is at top
    //Get last element that is shown
    //Do something

    //Else if scroll is at bottom
    //Get first element and do something

    //Else if scroll is at mid range
    //get first and last element that is shown
    //and do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no trivial solution for this problem (without adding plugins), however you can use the `scroll` jquery event to watch the current position of your div children elements and then work your logic on them.

We can know if our elements are visible **entirely**, inside the div area, if their css `top` property is >= 0 and in the same time `height`of *main div* value is less than (`top` + `height`) of *current div child*.

Look at this piece of the code:

```
$('#content_wrapper').scroll(function() {
   var areaHeight = $(this).height(); // gets the height of content_wrapper

   //will receive first/last elements found
   var first_ele = null;
   var last_ele = null;

   items.each(function(index, value) {
     var top = $(this).position().top; //top position of element
     var height = $(this).height();

     /* detection can be altered here */
     if (top > -1 && first_ele == null){ //first entirely visible element
         first_ele = this;
     }
     else if (top+height > areaHeight && last_ele == null){ 
         last_ele = $(items[index-1]);//the last entirely visible was the element before
     }

     // those not being first or last receive data-id back 
     $(this).children().first().html($(this).children().first().attr('data-id'));  
   });

   //action to first element, avoid first of list
   if(first_ele !== items[0])
     $(first_ele).children().first().html('test start');       
   //action to last element                     
   $(last_ele).children().first().html('test end');   
});
```

In this code we loop through `items` to detect *first* and *last* entirely visible elements like mentioned before. With them set, their html is replaced by test messages. The items that shouldn't receive actions have `inner html` overwritten with the `data-id`attribute.

You might need to tune a bit if you want even the **partial** ones to have an action, which is the block commented in the code, I've set up a fiddle with an example using actions in top/mid/bottom cases.

Full working **FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/nyupm/5/

Comment: Yes this look's pretty good! Have to study about it's functionallity but it's a huge help, thanks a lot!